# What's wrong with my SQL syntax?, i'm using DISTINCT and EXCEPT in it

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to use DISTINCT, NOT EXISTS, adn EXCEPT in one SQL syntax, but it's not working. This is my SQL syntax:

```
        SELECT DISTINCT S.ID, S.name
        FROM student AS S
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(   
            (SELECT course_id FROM course 
            WHERE dept_name = 'Biology')
            EXCEPT
            (SELECT T.course_id FROM takes AS T
            WHERE S.ID = T.ID)
        );
```

And this is the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'EXCEPT (SELECT T.course_id FROM takes AS T WHERE S.ID = T.ID))' at line 1
```

How to make it works, i can't solve it, guys help me..

Comment: `EXCEPT` does not exist in MySQL.

Comment: Double the Rahul, double the fun :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no `EXCEPT` in `MySQL`. Use a `NOT IN` rather like

```
    SELECT DISTINCT S.ID, S.name
    FROM student AS S
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(   
        SELECT course_id FROM course 
        WHERE dept_name = 'Biology' 
        AND course_id NOT IN 
        (SELECT T.course_id FROM takes AS T
        WHERE S.ID = T.ID)
    );
```

Comment: @Harry, define *Not Working*. Is it errors? If so then post the error.

Comment: ya error, this is the error: 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at
line 9

Comment: @Harry, yes, there was an extra `(`. edited answer ... try now.

Answer (score 2):

`EXCEPT` does not exist in MySql. You can try using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.ID, S.name
        FROM student AS S
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(   
            (SELECT course_id FROM course c left join takes T on  S.ID = T.ID
            WHERE c.dept_name = 'Biology')
        );
```